# Login Activated user MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My web application includes a confirmation email to confirm users (through email).
This piece works, the email gets send with the confirmationtoken and the user can click on the link and the user gets confirmed.

How can I get the activated user to directly (automatically) login? Something like

```
WebSecurity.ConfirmAccount(token);
WebSecurity.LogIn(??confirmeduser??);
```

How can I get this confirmeduser??

(NOTE: I am using the default MVC4 membership provider)

Comment: Is your authentication mechanism a "claims based authentication"?

Comment: May be this article can help you http://dotnetcodr.com/2013/02/28/claims-based-authentication-in-mvc4-with-net4-5-c-part-2-storing-authentication-data-in-an-authentication-session/

Comment: spcly the "authManager.Authenticate(string.Empty, claimsPrincipal);" in 9th code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have a database having the relation with your token and the user. Take a look at this [article](http://etproject.wordpress.com/2013/07/22/net-mvc-4-automatic-login-after-registration/):

This is a peace of code extracted from that article:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult RegisterConfirmation(string Id)
{
    if (WebSecurity.ConfirmAccount(Id))
    {
        using (var db = new UsersContext())
        {
            // Use ConfirmationToken to figure out UserId, then use that to get UserName.
            int userId = db.Memberships.Single(m => m.ConfirmationToken == Id).UserId;
            string userName = db.UserProfiles.Single(u => u.UserId == userId).UserName;

            // Authenticate user.
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    return View("ConfirmationFailure");
}
```

Comment: Voodoo I was trying to apply this piece of code, but I remembered I don't have access to the Memberships because they don't exist in de DbContext I have. How can I access these Memberships??